# How to invoke a function that has a parameter(s) without using parenthesis in Python

Tags: python, matplotlib, tkinter

I'm building a data visualization app in Python using Tkinter for the GUI and data science libraries Matplotlib, Seaborn, Pandas and NumPy for the backend.

I have the following line of code where `button["command"]` is the command for a Tkinter Button which is assigned to a function `self.create_analytics_dashboard(button_plots)` that creates a new Tkinter frame when the button is pressed. The `button plots` argument is an object responsible for displaying the right plots based on the button pressed.

```
        button["command"] = self.create_analytics_dashboard(button_plots)
```

There are 3 pertinent Tkinter frames to this problem:

1. main_dashboard
2. plots_dashboard
3. analytics_dashboard

The first 2 frames simply contain buttons that navigate to the next frame and the anaylytics_dashboard frame has buttons which displays the actual visualizations.

The expected order of these frames is as listed above however, due to the line where I assign the `button["command"]` aforementioned, the program skips the plots_dashboard and goes from the main_dashboard directly to the analytics_dashboard.

There are no error messages however, if I remove the parenthesis and the parameter inside it (`button_plots`) as shown in the line below the program will display the frames in the right order without skipping the plots_dashboard frame:

```
        button["command"] = self.create_analytics_dashboard
```

Obviously, I have tried Googling it but all the results just seem to talk about the difference between invoking functions with and without parenthesis or the purposes of each. [This article](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/python-invoking-functions-with-and-without-parentheses/) helps explain the difference quite succinctly:

> When we call a function with parentheses, the function gets execute and returns the result to the callable.
> In another case, when we call a function without parentheses, a function reference is sent to the callable rather than executing the function itself.

So, since the function works as intended when I don't use parenthesis i.e. send a function reference to the callable rather than executing the function itself, I tried using a partial function from the functools library to see if it would work:

```
        from functools import partial
        ...
        button_command = partial(self.create_analytics_dashboard)
        button["command"] = button_command(button_plots)
```

Unfortunately, nothing changed. The plots_dashboard frame was still skipped as before. I need a way to pass `button_plots` as an argument so it can be used in the `self.create_analytics_dashboard` function without using parenthesis since this will just execute the function rather than sending a function reference to the callable.

If there is another way of passing a variable from one function in a class to another function in the same class in Python then that could work as well. I simply need the `button_plots` variable to be available in the `self.create_analytics_dashboard` function one way or another.

Apologies for the long post but this has been bothering me for a long time so I tried to give as much as detail as possible. If anything in the question does not make sense please let me know. Any help is much appreciated.

Thanks

Comment: Is `button_plots` a global variable or a local variable?

Comment: @BryanOakley it is a local variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To use `functools.partial` you must include the arguments when you create the partial function:

```
button_command = partial(self.create_analytics_dashboard, button_plots)
button["command"] = button_command
```

Or, more concisely:

```
button["command"] = partial(self.create_analytics_dashboard, button_plots)
```